# **ERROR:** "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"?

Tags: jquery

**ERROR:** "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var rep = jQuery(".abc")
              .clone()
              .wrap("<div></div>")
              .parent().html()
              .replace(/select/g,"ul")
              .replace(/option/g,"li");

     jQuery(".abc").replaceWith(rep);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works as intended:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var rep = jQuery(".abc")
          .clone()
          .wrap("<div></div>")
          .parent().html()
          .replace(/select/g,"ul")
          .replace(/option/g,"li");

 jQuery(".abc").replaceWith(rep);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Maybe you’re missing a `.abc` element on your page. In that case `.html()` will return `undefined`.